# Any possible way to handle an action between WKWebView and Browser for selecting an image in iOS?

Tags: ios, webkit, ios11, wkwebview, input-type-file

I want to upload a static image on select of button (as described in below screenshot) `<input type="file">` on the web url from my app using `WKWebView`.

On click of **Choose File** button it will open default action sheet of device and after the selection of image, it will be uploaded on server. I want to interrupt the flow and upload my static image instead of user's selected image.

[image]
[image]

Is there any **observer** or **listener** so from there we can handle request and response. Upload an image using form-data API is not available.

Comment: I know this is not going to solve your issue, but what exactly are you trying to achieve? Why have a file input if you will ignore it? Why not just send your static image to your server without this useless interaction?

Comment: The problem is we don't handle the server and it's the requirement @MihaiFratu

Answer (score 0):

You can get a callback from WKWebView's element click action but you need to play with JavaScript code and the JSVirtualMachine which will help to get a callback in your swift class. and then you can do any action on click as like normal action

You can follow [this link](https://medium.com/swift-programming/from-swift-to-javascript-and-back-fd1f6a7a9f46)